# Ignore notices in ternary conditions

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I am wondering if it's possible to be selective in which context an undefined variable can be ignored. With ternary conditions, I like the idea that I can quickly set a default value for an undefined setting, like so:

```
$date = $_POST['date'] ?: date();
```

And to use this, I had to ignore `E_NOTICE` errors.

However, I don't really like the idea of all undefined variables being ignored, and accidentally using undefined variables to go unnoticed. So I am wondering if there is a possibility of some middle ground for this situation?

Just to clarify, I am aware of non-ternary solutions, such as

```
$date = (isset($_POST['date'])) ? $_POST['date'] : date();
// or
$date = date(); 
if(isset($_POST['date'])) {
   $date = $_POST['date'];
}
```

But what I'm trying to ask is, is there a way to reap the benefits of the shorthand ternary conditions, while still avoiding supressing notices for undefined variables.

Comment: You should always structure your code to account for notices/warnings/errors, not suppress or ignore them. I'm guessing what you're looking for is something like `$date = isset($_POST['date']) ? $_POST['date'] : date();`? If the POST is set, use that, if not use `date()`?

Answer (score 3):

Just prepend with `@`:

```
$date = @$_POST['date'] ?: date('Y-m-d');
        ^
```

Anyway, I would suggest to verify with `isset` instead:

```
$date = isset($_POST['date']) ? $_POST['date'] : date('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PHP 7+ then you can use [the null coalescing operator, `??`](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php) - it doesn't raise notices about unset variables. It also explicitly checks for null rather than empty variables - `?:` won't work intuitively for zero or an empty string, etc.

```
// Raises a notice if $_POST['date'] isn't set
$_POST['date'] ?: date();

// Won't raise a notice
$_POST['date'] ?? date();
```

As an aside, you might mean `time()` rather than `date()`, since the latter requires a format argument. Or you might have just left it out of your example.

Comment: No worries about date(), it was just an example I wrote straight on Stackoverflow, so I didn't "think it through" much.. :P

Answer (score 1):

```
@iainn said:
// Raises a notice if $_POST['date'] isn't set
$_POST['date'] ?: date();
// Won't raise a notice
$_POST['date'] ?? date();
```

Just pay attention the 2 forms are not equivalent, potentially exposing a very annoying bug to discover in future. While the ternary operator (?:) also checks for empty strings, the coalescing operator (??) does not! So, in the example:

```
// if $_POST['date'] contains '';
$_POST['date'] ?? date(); # it prints '' instead of date()
```

Answer (score 0):

This could work:

```
$date = ! empty($_POST['date']) ? $_POST['date'] : date();
```